# Is there any way to set GIF image as wallpaper in android programatically?

Tags: android

I am new to android and Currently i am developing setting live wallpaper in android device app.So, my question is that How to set gif image as wallpaper in any android device like live wallpaper.According to my project I have one imageadapter that handle the **GIF** image and send that **GIF** image to the Imageview and one activity to display that GIF image in to the imageview and in this activity I have one button named as **"Set as wallpaper"** and I am using **glide library** to display **GIF** image in imageview.

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(300);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(300);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FullScreenImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fly);
        imageView.setAnimation(anim);
        anim.start();

    }
    else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.mipmap.h1, R.mipmap.h2,
        R.mipmap.h3, R.mipmap.h4,
        R.mipmap.h5,R.mipmap.h6,
        R.mipmap.h7,R.mipmap.h8,
        R.mipmap.h9,R.mipmap.h10,
        R.mipmap.h11,R.drawable.gp3,
        R.drawable.gp2,R.drawable.gp,
        R.drawable.onehalloween
};
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity {


ImageView imageView,imgBack;
Button setWallpaper,save;
Drawable drawable;
Bitmap bitmap;
String ImagePath;
Uri URI;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image);
    //share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);


    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    //Get image fro Image adapter
    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int imageRes = bdl.getInt("imageID");

    //Setting up wallpaper
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    image.setImageResource(imageRes);
    if (image != null) {
        Log.v("Gif....","........" +image);
        Glide.with(this).load(imageRes).into(image);
    }
    setWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setWall);
    setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(imageRes);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                // Create layout inflator object to inflate toast.xml file
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                // Call toast.xml file for toast layout
                View toastRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_toast2, null);

                Toast toast = new Toast(context);

                // Set layout to toast
                toast.setView(toastRoot);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,
                        0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    //Header back button...for Mainactivity.java
    imgBack = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentLog9 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentLog9);
            finish();
            Intent in = new Intent(FullScreenImage.this,ExitDialog.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    //Save code
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageRes);

            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            ImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    bitmap,
                    "imageRes","imageRes"
            );

            URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            // Create layout inflator object to inflate toast.xml file
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            // Call toast.xml file for toast layout
            View toastRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_toast3, null);

            Toast toast = new Toast(context);

            // Set layout to toast
            toast.setView(toastRoot);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,
                    0,0 );
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotateimage);
    image.setAnimation(anim);
    anim.start();
}
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBack"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ce3c3c"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background="@color/fullimageback"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/header"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setWall"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wallpaper"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="@color/fullimageback"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="@color/fullimageback"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So,How i can achieve this type functionality. If anyoneknow help me.
Thanks in advance...